# Required permanent internet connection for Selenium Standalone Server

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I'm using Selenium Standalone Server with WebdriverIO and facing the problem that I always need to have working internet connection. Otherwise selenium refuses to start as it is not able to download chromedriver:

```
Error: Could not request headers from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.30/chromedriver_win32.zip: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443
```

I do not understand why it has to download it each time from the scratch although it was already downloaded during previous starts. Probably that's a bug. The problem is discussed here

https://github.com/vvo/selenium-standalone/issues/324

But no proper solution is provided, unfortunately. So, my question is, is there any way to configure the selenium server (maybe through wdio.conf.js of WebdriverIO) in order to avoid this annoying behaviour?